# Difference between 12Log2 and Log[2,12]?

Tags: math

My math is pretty weak, and I'm having confusion over the differences. I'm trying to find out the midi formula, to output frequency when I have midi value

```
MidiNumber = 69+12* Log2(440/Frequency)
```

So I derived
    Frequency = (-69 + 5280 Log2 + MidiNumber)/(12 Log2)

If I plugin things this works correctly
    440 = (-69 + 5280 Log2 + 69)/(12 Log2)

If I do this though things do not work correctly
    (-69 + Log[2, 5280.] + 69)/Log[2, 12.]

This is the output I get in my programming, I don't know exactly the difference between the two equations. Maybe it's 12*Log2, but is that 12*Log2[1] or, ...? No idea.

Comment: What language are your statements formatted for?

Comment: I'm trying to make my arduino accept midi numbers so I was just trying to translate the derived function into code.  (-69 + Log[2, 5280.] + 69)/Log[2, 12.] gives me something like 3.44 instead of 440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your confusion seems to be treating Log2(n) as Log2 * n. Log2 is actually a function, the inverse of which is 2^x.

So your derivation should go something as follows:

```
MidiNumber = 69 + 12 * Log2(440 / Frequency)
MidiNumber - 69 = 12 * Log2(440 / Frequency)
(MidiNumber - 69) / 12 = Log2(440 / Frequency)
2^((MidiNumber - 69) / 12) = 440 / Frequency
Frequency = 440 / 2^((MidiNumber - 69) / 12)
```